# List of dynamically created checkboxes in JavaScript all stay on the same line

Tags: javascript, html

I am iterating over objects and trying to put the text of each object on a new line in the list with a checkbox next to it. So far, I have everything printing out with a checkbox next to it but everything stays on the same line. I want to make sure they are separated as a list should be. Below is the code that is currently producing the above output. I have looked around at examples and I am following them so I am very confused as to where I am going so wrong. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I figured out the issue. Seemed to be entirely with the use of label. I instead just added the checkbox and description to the list item directly then append it and it started working as expected. WishI had better reasoning as to why the use of label mitigated the list functionality. New working code is shown below. Thanks everyone for making me think more critically.

```
var list = document.getElementById('status_list');

      //Iterates through all the post messages and displays them in a list
      for (var i = 0; i < pageposts.data.length; ++i){

                        var label= document.createElement("label");
          var checkbox;
          var li;
          var type;
          var message;
          var link;

          type = pageposts.data[i].type;
          message = pageposts.data[i].message;
          link = pageposts.data[i].link;
          if(typeof message != 'undefined'){
              li = document.createElement('li');

              checkbox = document.createElement("input");
              checkbox.type = "checkbox";  
              checkbox.value = "pair";       

              li.appendChild(checkbox);
              li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));

              li.appendChild(label);
              list.appendChild(li);
          }else{
              li = document.createElement('li');

              checkbox = document.createElement("input");
              checkbox.type = "checkbox";  
              checkbox.value = "pair";       

              li.appendChild(checkbox);
              li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(link));

              li.appendChild(label);
              list.appendChild(li);

        }

   }

<div id="find_list" data-role="page" align ="center">

<h2 id="pagename"></h2>
 <ul id="status_list">

 </ul>
```

Comment: That code won't produce anything without HTML and CSS, would you mind including those as well?

Comment: you have created var li, but have not used it anywhere.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and thus difficult to answer (where is "pageposts")  Since that does not exist in your presented sample, your code does nothing.

Comment: I have included the HTML as requested but it is only a div, header, and list. 'pageposts' is just an array with data I am display which is working fine. I really want to know why everything is appearing on one line and not being be split up to separate items in a list. I have tried making list items('li') and adding them to the status list but this doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are forget about `li` element.

Instead of this line:

`list.appendChild(label);`

You should add:

```
li.appendChild(label);
list.appendChild(li);
```

Comment: I tried this and it still all appears on the same line. I added my html in case there is something wrong with that. Thank you for answering.

Comment: The main issue seems to be with the label. Am I using that incorrectly? If I go back to only the text the the list appears just fine. When I attempt to add the checkbox and label things get weird.